# All non-isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

How can I find all non-isomorphic graphs with 2, 3 or 4 nodes, including not-connected ones?

I know that to graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, if there is a bijective depiction $f: V(G_1) \rightarrow V(G_2) $ so that $[x,y] \in E(G_1) \Leftrightarrow [f(x),f(y)] \in E(G_2)$.

How can I use this to solve the task?

Comment: Yes I am...but I have no Idea how to use such a matrix for my problem :(

Comment: $4$ is small enough that the easiest way is simply brute force. There are clearly two non-isomorphic graphs on $2$ nodes, one connected and the other not. There are four on $3$ nodes, one with $3$ components, one with $2$ components, and two connected. And the case of $4$ nodes is still manageable by hand.

Comment: If you just need to know what they are - assuming this is not just an exercise - there are libraries of such graphs online. For example, I found this by google-image searching for "non-isomorphic graph" :) http://wiki.smp.uq.edu.au/G-designs/index.php/Graphs_with_five_vertices

Comment: @gilleain It is an exercise ;)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand this with 2 nodes but can you explain again with 3 nodes?

Comment: @Babs: `*   *   *`; `*--*   *`; `*--*--*`; and $K_3$, a triangle.

Comment: thanks so much @BrianM.Scott!!!
Is this solution true: http://imgur.com/z3Kt4Hp ?

Comment: @Babs: Leider nicht ganz. $(3)$ and $(4)$ are isomorphic, as are $(6)$ and $(7)$, and $(10)$ and $(11)$. And you’re missing one graph with two components, a $K_3$ and an isolated vertex. There should be $11$ altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @BrianM.Scott

I guess this MUST be true now: http://i.imgur.com/0uWn06l.jpg

Comment: @Babs: Looks good now; you’re welcome!